# Installing Linux Mint on an external drive (bootloader location etc.)

Tags: linux, linux-mint, grub2, boot-loader, gparted

So I'm a bit anxious how to proceed, I don't want to cause any system issues, it doesn't help that after creating bootable USB and pre-partitioning SSD I saw ''*Configuration changed - Restart the system*'' few times during initial boot (Lenovo laptop, and this seems like a major issue where people are returning their laptops) - thankfully it's gone.
Also saw some comments saying there is a bug with Mint installer, that it will use first EFI partition it finds, irrespective of what you tell it. The recommendation is to disconnect internal drive, and I'm not able to do that, so hopefully there are another solutions.

I have 2021 Thinkpad with WIN10 (UEFI) and 500GB external SSD. I pre-partitioned my SSD with Gparted, allocating 400GB for LME (ext4) and 50GB in NTFS for files. I have a bootable USB ready with Linux Mind Edge 20.3 on it.

What I'm trying to accomplish:

1. When the external drive is disconnected, the laptop acts the same as now, meaning booting straight to Windows (saw some cases when after installing, the SSD needs to be connected for Windows to be able to boot - I don't want this to happen)
2. When the external drive is connected, I want to boot LME by pressing F12 and choosing a temporary startup device from UEFI, in my case external SSD
3. I want to be able to preserve all files and configuration settings in LME by running it this way, meaning it will not default each time the drive is disconnected
4. Be able to boot LME from this external drive by connecting it to another laptop, in a same way (#2 and #3)

It seems that the most important thing is the bootloader location, but I included the points above for other tips as well. Looks like there are many ways for this to go wrong, but I trust the community here for getting the right guide for my setup.

Comment: Does Mint use Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer with this old bug? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Many work arounds in bug comments. I prefer to partition in advance using gpt to be sure to have ESP on external drive.  I still have to unmount incorrect ESP &  mount correct one during install at password screen during install #55 or( #23 & #26). This is probably easier: Remove esp flag from Windows before install to second or external drive - Tim Richardson
https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator